# Solving round number in JS by using String

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Whatever language you choose, you may encounter a rounding problem. In fact, this is due to the limit of the required number of bits needed to get the right number after a calculation.

Simple example:

[image]

In javascript (like any other language), you may want to use a function to round the result after even a simple sum (with decimals) :

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately it's not always working as we expect.

[image]

That's why I created my own function which is based on a string version.
I read every char and make the round by myself so I'm not limited by the number of bits.

```
round(number, decimalsLength) {

// If the number does contains a scientific notation, we use a more traditionnal calculation method
if(number.toString().includes("e"))
    number = parseFloat(number.toFixed(4));

// Split the integer part and the decimal part
var number = (typeof number === "number") ? number : (number != null) ? parseFloat(number) : 0; // Return NaN for [null; {}]
var decimalsLength = decimalsLength || 0;
var array = (number+"").split(".");
var left = array[0];
var right = "1"+(array[1] || 0); // We add 1 to keep the left 0

// Round only if we have more decimal than needed
if(right.length-1 >= decimalsLength) {

    // Round up
    if(parseInt(right.substr(decimalsLength+1, 1)) >= 5)
        right = parseInt(right.substr(0, decimalsLength+1))+1;

    // If we moved to the upper integer
    if(right.toString().substr(0, 1) == 2) { // If the added 1 has became a 2
        var noDecimal = parseInt(right.toString().substr(1, decimalsLength)) == 0; // Return an integer if we no longer have any decimal
        left = (parseInt(left) + (number > 0 ? 1 : -1)).toString();
        return parseFloat(left + (noDecimal ?"":".") + (noDecimal?"":right.toString().substr(1, decimalsLength)));
    }
}

// Else, we don't need to round
var noDecimal = parseInt(right.toString().substr(1, decimalsLength)) == 0;
return parseFloat(left + (noDecimal?"":".") + (noDecimal?"":right.toString().substr(1, decimalsLength)));
```

}

I wanted to share this with you in case it can help, but also to have a feedback and improve the function if you find it useful.

Comment: Doing things like this is more a sign that you need to implement actual decimal arithmetic, hacking floats this way is not reliable.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be reliable? It solves the previous examples

Comment: OK let me put that a bit differently: even if it is reliable (which I don't know for sure whether it is or isn't), I would not be able to reason about whether it is or isn't, so I cannot discover whether it is reliable. Can you? By contrast, actual decimal arithmetic is not hard to reason about. Additionally, note that this function is inherently incapable of returning 1.04 for example, you can get a number that is *printed as* 1.04 but it will be 1.04000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625 (depending on the context in which that value is used, that may or may not matter)

Comment: If you call round(1.04000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625, 2) you will get a type number which value 1.04. That's because by manipulating the char we get a string of "1.04" after truncating the right decimals. Then the parseFloat convert it to a number which is not only a printed value.

I use this function after every sum or substract where decimals are implicated. I generated hundred of thousands accounting entries with this function, I had too much problems with the traditionnal methods.
I generated a million of tests and compared with Math.round(number*100)/100

Comment: My point was the value cannot be 1.04, it's impossible, there is no 64-bit float with that exact value. The best you can hope for is 1.04000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625, which is the closest representable value to 1.04. However, printing that number gives 1.04, so it seems you get 1.04, but you don't.

Comment: @Sébastien Josserand, The conversion of a number to a string can incur a roundings unless potentially  hundreds of characters are used.  Later attempting to round based on a `>= '5'` risks [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) errors.  This approach also has a problem with `number = parseFloat(number.toFixed(4));` converting small values to zero.  `round()` fails too many edge cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## document the return value

```
round(number, decimalsLength) {
```

The name suggests something similar to
[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)
documented function:

> Math.round()
>
> The Math.round() static method returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.

That's a crystal clear
[guarantee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
about the return value.

Your function offers no assurances at all about what's returned.

---

## document the input value

```
var number = (typeof number === "number") ? number : (number != null) ? parseFloat(number) : 0; // Return NaN for [null; {}]
```

Your `round()` is a
[total function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).
Silently accepting any and all types for
what ostensibly should be a `number`,
and mapping a subset of them to `0`,
sounds disastrous for the caller.

Much better to insist on one-or-more input types, perhaps FP and string,
and throw a fatal error if caller messed up by passing in some random object.

---

## be direct

```
var right = "1"+(array[1] || 0); // We add 1 to keep the left 0
```

Hacks such as this do not lead to maintainable code.

Say what you mean and mean what you say.
Starting with "234.567" and then assigning `right = "1567"`
tells the reader that `right` does not mean "the digits
to the right of the decimal point".
We're left with the identifier not having a clear meaning.
Break this out as a well-named helper if there's a transform you need.

---

## solve a general problem

```
if(right.length-1 >= decimalsLength) {
    ...
    if(parseInt(right.substr(decimalsLength+1, 1)) >= 5)
        right = ... [an integer expression, definitely not a string] ...

    if(right.toString().substr(0, 1) == 2) { 
        ...
        return ...
    }
}
...
return ... [expression which involves 'right'] ...
```

Wow, that's a lot of special cases.

First, extract helper, which would give you an opportunity
to name and to document that you're transforming from *this* to *that*.
Plus you could separately unit test the helpers.

Second, consider using FP arithmetic to solve this problem.
Your chief complaint seems to be that FP quantities describe
intervals on the real number line, and some are "a bit off",
a bit negative. You give the example of `10.395`,
which encodes an interval that *contains* 10.395,
but which starts at 10.394999...99905, leading to
unfortunate truncated string results.
For restricted input ranges, which you'd need to document,
you might be able to get away with always adding `epsilon = 1e-12`
to the input number, and then rounding, obviating the need for many `if`s.

Obtaining 100% code coverage via unit tests would pose some slight challenge,
given the current code.

---

## scaled integer

No app-level motivating use case was offered in the original submission.

It is possible that an app which cares about rounding
details of a very large set of FPs which includes `10.395`
may want a different approach.
Let's focus on the "two decimal places" case.

Consider advising app developers to work with integer number of cents,
rather than FP decimal number of dollars.
Format with two decimal places upon display.
For FP operations on a restricted range of integers,
conservatively the natural numbers less than a trillion,
FP calculations are always exact.
Fifty-three bits of significand is a lot of bits to
represent exact integer quantities.

---

As a consumer of this code,
I would not want to call into it,
as it is unclear what value it might return.

As a QA tester, I would not want
to be tasked with obtaining 100% code coverage.
(The OP, alas, did not include any automated testing.)

As a maintenance engineer on the team responsible for this library routine,
I would not be able to confidently add features or fix bugs, as the current
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
is unclear.
Recommend revising this code before attempting to merge it down to `main`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. As you may noticed, it looks more like a personal function, it need improvements.

The 2 returns give a parseFloat and may return NaN for a string input, and fatal error for null/undefined input (Math.round seems to return NaN in place of fatal error, I may make an update)
I don't know for the epsilon, we may want to add or remove it depending on the calculation. round(4) before a round(2) may be interesting too
Where should I update my new version? I should directly update the question?

I'm not sure there's a better solution than working with string

Comment: Good. Feel free to post new code in an [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), or perhaps request a [new review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Just "_do not change the code in the question after receiving an answer._" // I wholeheartedly agree with changing to a "string in / string out" API. Consider `.3 - .2 --> .0999...998`. The trouble with the current API is it is unclear what `number` _means_. It has a precise mathematical meaning, which you don't like and want to adjust via rounding. Scaled integer or string would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

**Questionable goal**

Code suffers from/abuses [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding).

Javascript numbers use [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) encoding.  That provides about 10<sup>19</sup> different values.
10.395 is *not* one of them as it is not a [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), an integer times a power of 2.

In the vicinity of 10.395 are encodable values:
10.394999999999999573674358543939888477325439453125
10.3950000000000013500311979441903531551361083984375

As a string "10.395" converted to a number, it is convert to the closer, yet lesser one.

With OP's code, both of these return a value near 10.40.

So if `number` is a *string* like "10.395", 10.40 is a good result.
Yet if `number` is a *number* prints like 10.395, it really is 10.394999... and 10.39 is a good result.